# Workflow failed to start

Tags: workflow, permissions

I made few workflows that check the current item's status and updates few counters, using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Until now they were working well.

After trying to update specific item's permissions (also with a workflow) things started to get bad, and now both of the workflows won't start. 
the error is "failed to start". (yep... not so informative).

After some research I've noticed that once I remove the line that try to access information about the current Item, the workflow starts.

Have any idea what can be the cause? I guess it's related to permission mess but have no idea how.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the ULS logs around the time that this happens?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem. It relates to a recent Microsoft security update. Follow the instructions here to resolve
https://collab365.community/forum/topics/default-sharepoint-workflows-are-failed-to-start-since-17th-of-september/